# MySQL: update row based on if condition

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I update every column in a row if a certain condition in the column is met?
Say if the status column of that row is 'underReview', then update the whole row with the request body. If the status column has other values, then do not execute the SQL query? I am using v8 btw.

I have tried the query below but it shows error.

```
IF ((SELECT status FROM tableName) = "underReview" WHERE id = ?) 
THEN
    UPDATE tableName
    SET columnA = ?, columnB = ?, columnC = ?, columnD = ?
    WHERE id = ?;
END IF
```

Comment: tnkh, welcome to the exquisite world of relational algebra, where procedural algorithms do not quite apply. Please, make no step further until you really understand what's implied on @Nick's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the condition on `status` to the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnA = ?, columnB = ?, columnC = ?, columnD = ?
WHERE id = ? AND status = 'underReview';
```